# Compositions of $n$ with $0$ to $n$ elements with elements no greater than 6.

Tags: combinatorics

$a_n$ is the ways to pick an integer $i$ such that $i \geq 0$, then roll a dice with six sides $i$ times so that the sum of the outcomes of the dice rolls is $n$.  I am looking for a generating function for $\langle a \rangle$ which is written as a ratio of two polynomials that each have at most three terms.  I am having a bit of trouble intuitively understanding generating functions and am unsure how to approach this problem.  I am only looking for some insight on how this should be approached.

Edit: My understanding of the setup for this problem is in the title.

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear. Are you asking for the number of $i$ such that it is possible to get $n$ with $i$ dice rolls, or, for given $n$, the total number of ways to get $n$ by rolling $i$ dice summed over $i$?

Comment: I'm looking for the total number of ways to get $n$ by rolling a dice (six sided) $i$ times summed over $i$.  So my understanding at this point is the sum of compositions of $n$ with $i$ elements with elements no larger than 6 for $0 \leq i \leq n$.

Comment: @Mroog It will help a lot of you know a recurrence relation between $a_n$ and smaller values of $a_{n-1}$, $a_{n-2}$, etc.  Can you find one?

Comment: If you're looking for the generating function $\sum_n a_n x^n$, then you don't have to think about the $n$ values separately at all; you can simply consider each number of rolls $i$ separately, find the corresponding generating function, and sum over $i$.